# TomEE + Omnifaces - test - SEVERE: CDI Beans module deployment failed

Tags: jsf, testing, omnifaces, apache-tomee

I use Omnifaces in a project. All well and good.
The issue I have is that I can't test the project, because I can't get TomEE to start, regardless of what method I use (EJBContainer, ApplicationComposer or Arquillian embedded).

It seems that Omnifaces has a beans issue or something.
I made a sample maven project https://bitbucket.org/zmirc/tomee-omnifaces-bug

You can see that I tried to do it in 3 ways, but I keep getting the same error.
If you just comment Omnifaces from pom.xml, you can see that TomEE starts properly and all tests succeed, so it's something between TomEE and Omnifaces.

Some help would be much appreciated, because it's a big stop for me.
I reported the issue on TomEE's forum as well: http://tomee-openejb.979440.n4.nabble.com/TomEE-Omnifaces-test-SEVERE-CDI-Beans-module-deployment-failed-td4671597.html

Here is the error. You can see it by yourself if you try the sample project. Just start the test with Maven.

I'm using TomEE 1.7.0 and Omnifaces 1.8.1.

```
INFO: OpenWebBeans Container is starting...
Sep 04, 2014 12:30:42 PM org.apache.webbeans.plugins.PluginLoader startUp
INFO: Adding OpenWebBeansPlugin : [CdiPlugin]
Sep 04, 2014 12:30:42 PM org.apache.webbeans.plugins.PluginLoader startUp
INFO: Adding OpenWebBeansPlugin : [OpenWebBeansJsfPlugin]
Sep 04, 2014 12:30:42 PM org.apache.webbeans.config.BeansDeployer validateInjectionPoints
INFO: All injection points were validated successfully.
Sep 04, 2014 12:30:42 PM org.apache.openejb.cdi.OpenEJBLifecycle startApplication
SEVERE: CDI Beans module deployment failed
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.omnifaces.util.Beans.getReference(Beans.java:78)
        at org.omnifaces.util.Beans.getReference(Beans.java:66)
        at org.omnifaces.cdi.eager.EagerExtension.load(EagerExtension.java:111)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.apache.webbeans.event.ObserverMethodImpl.notify(ObserverMethodImpl.java:266)
        at org.apache.webbeans.event.NotificationManager.fireEvent(NotificationManager.java:482)
        at org.apache.webbeans.container.BeanManagerImpl.fireEvent(BeanManagerImpl.java:446)
        at org.apache.webbeans.container.BeanManagerImpl.fireLifecycleEvent(BeanManagerImpl.java:436)
        at org.apache.webbeans.config.BeansDeployer.fireAfterDeploymentValidationEvent(BeansDeployer.java:374)
        at org.apache.webbeans.config.BeansDeployer.deploy(BeansDeployer.java:205)
        at org.apache.openejb.cdi.OpenEJBLifecycle.startApplication(OpenEJBLifecycle.java:194)
        at org.apache.openejb.cdi.ThreadSingletonServiceImpl.initialize(ThreadSingletonServiceImpl.java:160)
        at org.apache.openejb.cdi.CdiBuilder.build(CdiBuilder.java:41)
        at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:797)
        at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:623)
        at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1248)
        at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.configureStart(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1087)
        at org.apache.tomee.catalina.GlobalListenerSupport.lifecycleEvent(GlobalListenerSupport.java:130)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5378)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649)
        at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.deployWar(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:648)
        at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.deployWebApps(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:618)
        at org.apache.tomee.catalina.deployment.TomcatWebappDeployer.deploy(TomcatWebappDeployer.java:43)
        at org.apache.tomee.embedded.Container.deploy(Container.java:362)
        at org.apache.tomee.embedded.Container.deploy(Container.java:348)
        at org.apache.openejb.arquillian.embedded.EmbeddedTomEEContainer.deploy(EmbeddedTomEEContainer.java:140)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController$3.call(ContainerDeployController.java:161)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController$3.call(ContainerDeployController.java:128)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController.executeOperation(ContainerDeployController.java:271)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController.deploy(ContainerDeployController.java:127)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.DeploymentExceptionHandler.verifyExpectedExceptionDuringDeploy(DeploymentExceptionHandler.java:50)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.ContainerDeploymentContextHandler.createDeploymentContext(ContainerDeploymentContextHandler.java:78)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.ContainerDeploymentContextHandler.createContainerContext(ContainerDeploymentContextHandler.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:145)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:116)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:67)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController$1.perform(ContainerDeployController.java:95)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController$1.perform(ContainerDeployController.java:80)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController.forEachDeployment(ContainerDeployController.java:263)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController.forEachManagedDeployment(ContainerDeployController.java:239)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController.deployManaged(ContainerDeployController.java:79)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:145)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:116)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:67)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.ContainerEventController.execute(ContainerEventController.java:101)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createSuiteContext(TestContextHandler.java:65)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createClassContext(TestContextHandler.java:84)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:145)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:116)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor.beforeClass(EventTestRunnerAdaptor.java:80)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$2.evaluate(Arquillian.java:190)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.multiExecute(Arquillian.java:345)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.access$200(Arquillian.java:49)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$3.evaluate(Arquillian.java:207)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.run(Arquillian.java:155)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:53)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:123)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:104)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:164)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:110)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:175)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcessWhenForked(SurefireStarter.java:107)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:68)
```

Error with 2.0-SNAPSHOT on 09.05.2014

```
INFO - Adding OpenWebBeansPlugin : [CdiPlugin]
INFO - Adding OpenWebBeansPlugin : [OpenWebBeansJsfPlugin]
INFO - All injection points were validated successfully.
SEVERE - CDI Beans module deployment failed
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.omnifaces.util.Beans.getReference(Beans.java:101)
    at org.omnifaces.util.Beans.getReference(Beans.java:88)
    at org.omnifaces.cdi.eager.EagerExtension.load(EagerExtension.java:111)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.webbeans.event.ObserverMethodImpl.notify(ObserverMethodImpl.java:266)
    at org.apache.webbeans.event.NotificationManager.fireEvent(NotificationManager.java:482)
    at org.apache.webbeans.container.BeanManagerImpl.fireEvent(BeanManagerImpl.java:446)
    at org.apache.webbeans.container.BeanManagerImpl.fireLifecycleEvent(BeanManagerImpl.java:436)
    at org.apache.webbeans.config.BeansDeployer.fireAfterDeploymentValidationEvent(BeansDeployer.java:374)
    at org.apache.webbeans.config.BeansDeployer.deploy(BeansDeployer.java:205)
    at org.apache.openejb.cdi.OpenEJBLifecycle.startApplication(OpenEJBLifecycle.java:194)
    at org.apache.openejb.cdi.ThreadSingletonServiceImpl.initialize(ThreadSingletonServiceImpl.java:160)
    at org.apache.openejb.cdi.CdiBuilder.build(CdiBuilder.java:41)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:797)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:623)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1248)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.configureStart(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1087)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.GlobalListenerSupport.lifecycleEvent(GlobalListenerSupport.java:130)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5378)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.deployWar(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:648)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.deployWebApps(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:618)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.deployment.TomcatWebappDeployer.deploy(TomcatWebappDeployer.java:43)
    at org.apache.tomee.embedded.Container.deploy(Container.java:362)
    at org.apache.tomee.embedded.EmbeddedTomEEContainer$EmbeddedTomEEContainerProvider.createEJBContainer(EmbeddedTomEEContainer.java:140)
    at javax.ejb.embeddable.EJBContainer.createEJBContainer(EJBContainer.java:56)
    at zmirc.tomee.omnifaces.TestUtils.getEJBContainer(TestUtils.java:23)
    at zmirc.tomee.omnifaces.EJBContainerTest.start(EJBContainerTest.java:18)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:123)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:104)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:164)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:110)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcessWhenForked(SurefireStarter.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:68)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got an answer on TomEE forum.
A temporary solution is to fallback to Omnifaces 1.7 or to upgrade to 1.10-SNAPSHOT.

Comment: Thank you for this question/answer. This problem suggests that OpenWebBeans CDI implementation as used by TomEE failed to inject `BeanManager` during  `@Observes AfterDeploymentValidation` event. Although I don't think that OmniFaces 2.0 SNAPSHOT would work, but if you have the environment and chance, can you please give the 2.0 SNAPSHOT snapshot a try as well and let me know?

Comment: @BalusC You're welcome. I've just tried with 2.0, but a similar error appeared. I added the error log into the main question post. I posted a link to a sample maven project, so you can easily try as well, just change the Omnifaces version.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Yes, I just fixed it: https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/commit/e03b1777536d5fe4207ec928eb510396fa1bcd7e Can you please try today's 2.0 snapshot? https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/omnifaces/omnifaces/2.0-SNAPSHOT/